# Java Swing Layout

Tags: java

I would like the following lay out...

- JButtons on top along side eachother.
- The JTextArea should be *under* the buttons.
- The JTextArea should also have a *scrollbar*.
  ...for the code below.

  ```
  JPanel jp = new JPanel();   
  One = new JButton("One");   
  Two = new JButton("Two");    
  TestOutput = new JTextArea();

  jp.add(One);
  jp.add(Two);
  jp.add(TestOutput);
  ```

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword is layering - having JPanel on JPanel.

Comment: There are some aspects of that example that are excellent, and others that are less so.  E.G. +1 `new JTextArea(4, 35);`, -1 `setMinimumSize`/`setSize`.  (The first makes the 2nd redundant.)  Overall +1.  Please consider rolling a compilable/runnable example in future - it often only takes an extra handful of LOC.

Answer (score 3):

Use a nested layout: To a [`JPanel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) having  [`BorderLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html),

- add a `JPanel` having `FlowLayout` for the buttons to the `NORTH`
- and a `JScrollPane` for the `JTextArea` to the `CENTER`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [GridBagLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html)

See this for more help : [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

Now note that the `JTextarea` to have a scrollbar have nothing to do with layouts.

See this for more help in that context : [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Comment: I was turned against this answer as soon as I saw `GridBagLayout`.  While GBL is powerful, it is also longer to write and harder to use and debug than a nested layout (for this simple GUI arrangement).  OTOH it includes a link to the J7 docs, and 2 links to the tutorial, one on a matter on which we all seem to agree (scroll pane).  +1

Answer (score 2):

The `FlowLayout` in a `JPanel` for the `JButton` instances is one way to go.  You might also use a [`JToolBar`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JToolBar.html) for the buttons.

[image: Buttons and TextArea Layout] [image: Buttons and TextArea Layout w. toolbar on RHS]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class ButtonsAndTextAreaLayout {

    ButtonsAndTextAreaLayout() {
        JPanel gui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5,5));

        // use a toolbar for the buttons
        JToolBar tools = new JToolBar();
        // use firstWordLowerCase for attribute/method names.
        JButton one = new JButton("One");
        JButton two = new JButton("Two");

        tools.add(one);
        tools.add(two);

        // provide hints as to how large the text area should be
        JTextArea testOutput = new JTextArea(5,20);

        gui.add(tools, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        gui.add(new JScrollPane(testOutput), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, gui);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ButtonsAndTextAreaLayout();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a GridBagLayout as suggested, or nest multiple layout managers such as:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
JButton oneButton = new JButton("One");
JButton twoButton = new JButton("Two");
buttonPanel.add(oneButton);
buttonPanel.add(twoButton);

JTextArea output = new JTextArea();
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(output);

frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
frame.add(scrollPane);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```